# android what kind encoder is MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.Default?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I don't understand what kind of encoder is used by `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.Default`.

Here is the reference: [CLICK HERE TO REFERENCE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html#DEFAULT)

and it does not tell me what kind of encoder is used.

Does anyone know that? Thanks.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/media/MediaRecorder.java

Comment: @barn.gumbl Thanks for your reply, but there's only `Default = 0` same as Android Reference in this file. I cannot know what encoder is used in `Default` mode.